# How do I execute code when a certain tabpage is entered?

Tags: vb.net

My application is supposed to resize the application window when a certain tabpage is entered. But I can't seem to find a working solution to this.

This is in VS 2010 and in VB.NET Windows Forms. I have 3 tabpages on a single tabcontrol.

```
Private Sub TabControl1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TabControl1.SelectedIndexChanged
If TabControl1.TabPages(1).Focused = True Then
        Me.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(369, 216) // Resizes Form
    ElseIf TabControl1.TabPages(2).Focused = True Then
        Me.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(788, 580) // Resizes Form
    End If
End Sub
```

It literally does nothing when this is executed, but has no errors in the IDE. It is supposed to resize the form to either 369, 216 or 788, 580 depending on which tabpage I click.

I've already tried the SelectedTab method, but with no luck:

```
If TabControl1.SelectedTab = TabPage1 Then
    ...
End If
```

This is the error I get from that code:

```
Operator '=' is not defined for types 'System.Windows.Forms.TabPage' and 'System.Windows.Forms.TabPage'.
```

Comment: The name of the event you're handling should be the clue.  The `SelectedIndexChanged` event is raised when the `SelectedIndex` property changes.  Maybe you should use that property to determine what it has changed to.  You also have the `SelectedTab` property you could use.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Thank you very much for your short reply time. I've edited the question, showing what happened when I did use the SelectedTab method. I forgot to mention that I had already tried beforehand.

Comment: @LarsTech I think this may have worked (:D), but try not to put C# code on a VB.NET question, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the selected tab to compare instead of the focused event.

```
Private Sub TabControl1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TabControl1.SelectedIndexChanged
    If TabControl1.SelectedTab Is TabPage1 Then
        Me.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(369, 216) // Resizes Form
    ElseIf TabControl1.SelectedTab Is TabPage2 Then
        Me.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(788, 580) // Resizes Form
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Why wouldn't '=' work?? It's essentially the same thing as 'Is'!

Comment: @w60, no, `=` and `Is` are not the same thing. `=` is used for value comparison while `Is` is used for reference comparison. Most reference types, i.e. classes, only support reference comparison so only support `Is` for equality comparison.  For some reference types, value comparison makes sense, e.g. the `String` class.  That means that you can use `=` or `Is` with `Strings` but they don't always produce the same result so you need to know which one to use and why.  It's almost always value equality you care about for `Strings` but only reference equality makes sense for `TabPages`.

Comment: Also, if you use `SelectedIndex` rather than `SelectedTab` then you're comparing `Integers` rather than `TabPages`, so you are using value comparison.  That also means that you can use `Select Case`.  The end result is the same but the code could be considered a little cleaner.